# Array Push with key is returning error

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

i'm trying to build some son objects from mysqli query. I want to create one array which will contain many array. But i'm getting some error

```
Error: [12-Mar-2015 02:56:23 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/bud/public_html/cp/function/receivable.php on line 18
```

here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('../configuration.php');
$con=new mysqli($hostname,$dbusername,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}
if(isset($_POST['date'])){
  $date=$_POST['date'];
  $receivable= array();
  if($date==="All"){
  $q1="SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_status='completed' AND due > '0.00' ORDER BY id DESC";
  }else{
  $q1="SELECT * FROM orders WHERE DATE(time) = '$date' AND order_status='completed' AND due > '0.00' ORDER BY id DESC";
  }
  $result=$con->query($q1);
  while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
  //$receivable['orders'][]=array($row);
  array_push($receivable['orders'][], array('id' => $row['id'], 'due' => $row['due'] ));
}
  echo json_encode($receivable);


}  
?>
```

How to insert array with key into `$receivable['orders'][];`
I would like to create more array like `$receivable['client'][];`
and would like to push variable with keys into $receivable['orders'][] like id =>, due=> , paid=>,

Answer (score 2):

You can simple make some changes in your code and it will work.

```
$receivable['orders'][]= array('id' => $row['id'], 'due' => $row['due'] );
```

This will give you numeric array as array_push();

Answer (score 0):

It has to be done this way...Parameter 1 has to be array.

```
// define array
$receivable['orders'] = array();

array_push($receivable['orders'], array('id' => $row['id'], 'due' => $row['due'] ));
```

Comment: i've tried your lines but still it returning
`PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/businesscraftsbd/public_html/cp/function/receivable.php on line 21`

Answer (score 0):

As in the multi-dimensional array an entry is another array, specify the index of that value to array_push:

> array_push($receivable['orders'], array('id' => $row['id'], 'due' =>
>   $row['due'] ));